# Montar check box com valores 1 e 0 angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox

Tenho uma tela que há um check box.. vejamos;

```
<div class="form-group col-md-9 pull-right">
              <label>Ativo:</label> 
               <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="pessoa.pessoasFisicas.flagAtivo" value="" />Sim
              </label>

              </div>
```

Recebo da minha api no meu front o seguinte flagAtivo:1 e, obviamente 0 quando pertinente. 
A questão é que não monta na tela .. sempre vem desmarcado o componente, independentemente se ou 1.

Tenho uma função que transforma true e ou false para 1 e 0.

```
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
        this.value ^= 1;
    });
```

esse é o metodo que traz o valor da flag

```
$http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/user/pessoasFisicas/'+ pes.idPessoa,
            //async: true
        }).then(function (response) {   
          $scope.pessoa.pessoasFisicas = response.data[0];
          flagAtivo:1 // resposta do método GET
```

Comment: Aonde está a parte do código que recebe o valor pertinente ao checkbox?

Comment: editei a pergunta @RafaelSalomão

Comment: Qual motivo do atributo value neste input? Usando angular e escutando um evento em jQuery?

Comment: Na verdade é para transformar um valor booleano em um valor numérico.

Comment: humm..posta como resposta para eu dar o ok aqui e encerrar a pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você faz esse request por GET para pegar o valor do checkbox dentro da função calback do request é aonde precisa setar o valor para o campo. 
O evento onchange só é chamado quando o usuário altera o valor do campo checkbox.

> Se você quiser chamar o onchange, você pode usar  [Jquery Trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger), isso irá executar todos os manipuladores e comportamentos anexados aos elementos correspondentes para o tipo de evento fornecido. Em linhas gerais irá simular o comportamento onchange do seu checkbox como se o usuário tivesse efetuado uma mudança.